# Duplicate result when looping data in Adonisjs

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, adonis.js

I want to return two data different with double looping from one data json. But result of looping is same.. this is my input, looping process and output:

```
"detail": [
        {
            "qty": 2,
            "price": 1000,
            "item_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "qty": 5,
            "price": 100000,
            "item_id": "2"
        }
    ]
```

this is first process looping to create **detail_id**:

```
const detail = request.input("detail");
const history = request.input("detail");

            for (var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
                if(!detail[i].detail_id) {
                    detail[i].detail_id = nanoid(21);
                }
                console.log(detail[i]);
                //output:
                // [
                   // {
                      // "qty": 2,
                      // "price": 1000,
                      // "item_id": "1",
                      // "detail_id": "fDRS0NIaoNoS9kiauypjy"
                   // },
                   // {
                      // "qty": 5,
                      // "price": 100000,
                      // "item_id": "2",
                      // "detail_id": "fDRS0NIaoNoS9kiauypjy"
                   // }
                 //]
             }
```

second looping to create **history_id**:

```
             for (var x = 0; x < history.length; x++) {
                if(!history[x].history_id) {
                    history[x].history_id = nanoid(21);
                }
                console.log(history[x]);
                //output:
                // [
                   // {
                      // "qty": 2,
                      // "price": 1000,
                      // "item_id": "1",
                      // "detail_id": "fDRS0NIaoNoS9kiauypjy"
                   // },
                   // {
                      // "qty": 5,
                      // "price": 100000,
                      // "item_id": "2",
                      // "detail_id": "fDRS0NIaoNoS9kiauypjy"
                   // }
                 //]
             }
```

the result of second looping still same with first looping, what's wrong with this code?

```js
const requestInput = [{
    "qty": 2,
    "price": 1000,
    "item_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "qty": 5,
    "price": 100000,
    "item_id": "2"
  }
];

const detail = requestInput;
const history = requestInput;

function nanoid(id) {
  return 'fDRS0NIaoNoS9kiauypjy';
}

for (var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
  if (!detail[i].detail_id) {
    detail[i].detail_id = nanoid(21);
  }
}
console.log(detail);

for (var x = 0; x < history.length; x++) {
  if (!history[x].history_id) {
    history[x].history_id = nanoid(21);
  }
}
console.log(history);
```

Comment: Can you try `const detail = {...request.input("detail")};
const history = {...request.input("detail")};` ?

Comment: @LevBuchel i think `request.input("detail")` gives an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make DEEP copies of the data you're passing in. Right now both detail and history are pointing at the same object. Using the [...data] will create a shallow copy. This will not suffice as we have nested data. Lodash is a popular tool for deep copying: https://lodash.com/

```
let data = [
  {
    qty: 2,
    price: 1000,
    item_id: "1"
  },
  {
    qty: 5,
    price: 100000,
    item_id: "2"
  }
];

// These are both referencing the same object
const detail = data;
const history = data;

for (var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
  if (!detail[i].detail_id) {
    detail[i].detail_id = 10;
  }
}
console.log(detail);
// The first loop is adding on detail_id
// [ { qty: 2, price: 1000, item_id: '1', detail_id: 10 },
//   { qty: 5, price: 100000, item_id: '2', detail_id: 10 } ]


for (var x = 0; x < history.length; x++) {
  if (!history[x].history_id) {
    history[x].history_id = 10;
  }
}
console.log(history);

// The second loop adds on history_id
// [ { qty: 2,
//     price: 1000,
//     item_id: '1',
//     detail_id: 10,
//     history_id: 10 },
//   { qty: 5,
//     price: 100000,
//     item_id: '2',
//     detail_id: 10,
//     history_id: 10 } ]
```

Comment: hmm, but how to remove detail_id from second looping? **detail_id** still include in ```history```

Comment: I updated my answer above, but to try to explain it better you need to create a deep copy if the object. Right now details and history are referencing the same thing. Try using: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep :)